# How to put the focus to a TextBox in OnNavigatedTo event?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

In Windows 8, when a page is navigated, I need to put the focus to a specific TextBox.

I used:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    myControl.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
}
```

But it does not work. However, if I call `myControl.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);` from a button click event, it works fine.

How can I set the focus to a TextBox when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try calling `myControl.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);`
with `this.Dispatcher`

A code sample:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(
        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () => myControl.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard));
}
```

Comment: for me myControl.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard) working by adding loaded event on windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myControl.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
```

and set this `control(mycontrol)` as the first control in your XAML code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour to get to know how this site works and what it is for. Consider formatting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Phone 8.1 add a Loaded event to the page and call the focus in there instead of OnNavigatedTo event

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SearchTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding it in the Loaded event of the TextBox:

xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" 
     Loaded="SearchTextBox_Loaded"/>
```

in the code behind .cs:

```
private void SearchTextBox_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SearchTextBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
}
```